# What is wrong with my lock_pairs function in problem set 3, Tideman?

Tags: c, cs50

I am using the depth-first search function named `dfsa_helper` to find a cycle, and the `check50` program says my function did not lock all non-cyclical pairs correctly, and I need help discovering where the problem is coming from.

```
bool dfs(int debut, int perdent) {
    if (debut == perdent)
        return true;

    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++) {
        if (locked[debut][i]) {
            if (dfs(i, perdent))
                return true;
            else if (!dfs(i, perdent))
                continue;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

void lock_pairs(void) {
    // TODO
    for (int i = 0; i < pair_count; i++) {
        if (!dfs(pairs[i].winner, pairs[i].loser)) {
            locked[pairs[i].winner][pairs[i].loser] = true;
        }
        else if (dfs(pairs[i].winner, pairs[i].loser)) {
            locked[pairs[i].winner][pairs[i].loser] = false;
        }
    }
  
    return;
}
```

The `check50` function says my function did not lock all noncyclical pairs correctly.

Comment: That means you did not test all of the interesting cases. What have you tested and what were the results?

Comment: If you're going to use global variables (_don't_) then you especially need to show a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).